# automating setting ssis parameters for multiple projects in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012, msbi

I have SSISDB with 1000 projects in SSIS 2012,i have migrated this SSISDB to other server can anyone help me how to update the parameter values server name present in SSISDB to new servers